When uploading metadata for a new token do I use Akords vault or storage?
I found out the github has been archived and I found out that the new method is to use cli with metaboss, the tutorials I read say, put the .json and logo.png into akord arweave but, when I open my akord panel there is vault(public/private) , and storage(perm and cloud) , what's the FULL walkthrough to get this? I have the raw.github uri up and the metadata.json made. I was following https://mafyuh.com/posts/spl-token-cli/ but, it isn't specific enough, I want to know if I'm making a vault or a storage and what setting to tick off correctly so i don't have to keep redoing it. Thank you!

1 - Choose the Vault Type
Vault: This is typically used for sensitive or private data, but it can also be used for data you want strictly controlled access to.
Since you're looking to store token assets like metadata.json and logo.png that need to be publicly accessible, you should use the Storage option instead of Vault.
2 - Select Storage Type
Permanent Storage: This option uses Arweave, a blockchain-based storage solution that ensures data permanence. For token metadata and images that need to be permanently accessible, this is the recommended choice.
Cloud Storage: More temporary and might not suit the needs of blockchain-based assets which require immutable and permanent availability.
Note: If your creating a MemeCoin, Cloud Storage may be a viable option if your not looking at a market that will stick around long-term.
https://ardrive.io/how-much-does-it-cost-to-store-on-arweave/#non-perma
3 - Use the URLs in Your SPL Token's Metadata
Once you have stored your images correctly update your metadata.json with the correct URLs
For cloud storage, make sure the URLs are stable and review them periodically, if you do not want to have the need to periodically check your URLs and want to be done with it once they have been included in your MetaData then a permanent storage option might be the best approach vs a cloud based approach.

If this answer was helpful please do not forget to upvote/select a answer @Keola
